# If I type 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit' in the terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which version of CUDA is installed?

Tags: cuda

If I type 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit' in the terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which version of CUDA is installed? I need to know what's going to happen without actually running the command.

Answer (score 0):

`7.5.18-0ubuntu1`

You can check it using `apt-cache showpkg [PACKAGE_NAME]` or `dpkg -l [PACKAGE_NAME]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain this information using `apt-cache policy`

```
$ apt-cache policy nvidia-cuda-toolkit
nvidia-cuda-toolkit:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.5.18-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     7.5.18-0ubuntu1 500
```